# Rename a specific column in a multiindex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Multiindex df like this:

[image]

I just want to rename the first column in level 1. So i tried this code:

```
p1tmaxt.columns.set_levels(['MES_DIA'],level=1,inplace=True)
```

And i also tried this code:

```
p1tmaxt.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(p1tmaxt.rename(columns={('', ''): ('', 'MES_DIA')}))
```

Do you know how to rename an specific column of multiindex? I know that `.set_levels` is for many columns but i dont want to rename the other columns. And i have 75 multiindex columns. My df is 366x75.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try via `pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples()` method and list comprehension:

```
df.columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
           [(x,y) if (x,y)!=('', '') else ('', 'MES_DIA') for x,y in df.columns]
                                    )
```